# Como gerar variáveis incrementadas com Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variáveis

Gostaria de saber como gerar variáveis incrementadas, por exemplo:

```
var camada = 0
for (i=0; i=20;i++){
    var "camada" + i + 1 = 12
}
```

Sei que o código não esta correto, mas escrevi para melhor ilustrar o que gostaria de fazer, tem quer gerar de modo automático as variáveis *camada1*, *camada2*, *camada3*,.. *camada20*.

Comment: Se essas variáveis forem globais, *até que é possível*: basta usar `window["camada" + (i+1)] = 12;` (atenção à associatividade do operador `+`). Daí você poderia acessá-la, digamos, como `x = camada4;`. Mas como já dito nas respostas, isso é uma má ideia, ainda que não fossem globais, melhor usar um array mesmo ou talvez um objeto.

Comment: Podes explicar qual é a fincionalidade onde precisas disto? Se referires o problema final podemos dar a solução mais acertada.

Comment: Estou criando uma web Page, para caucular as tensões no solo, cada camada de solo tem Altura e Peso Especifico

Criei um input que a pessoa digita a quantidade de camadas. Se o usuario digitar 5 por exemplo, sera gerada 10 inputs, 5 para altura e 5 para Peso Especifico...

Entao para cada camada eu tenho que gerar as varáveis para fazer os cáuculos....

Por isso que preciso gerar as variaveis de cada camada...eu criei elas como objetos, no caso uma nova camada eu so istanciaria ela, mas ainda fico com o mesmo problema

Comment: Quero fazer uso da seguinte forma
---for (var i=0; i<20; i++) {
 document.getElementById("espessuraCamada"+(i+1)).innerHTML=" "+camada(i+1).altura +"m"

Comment: Vou Testar...valeu ja ja trago a resposta

Comment: Amigo, vc acertou em cheio, era isso mesmo que eu queria...muito obrigado

var camadas = {};
for (var i = 0; i <= 20; ++i) {
    camadas["camada" + i] = { 'altura': 'altura' + i,
                              'peso': 'peso' + i};
}

Comment: @JacobAthias Ótimo. Se possível marque a [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/62883/6454) **como a que resolveu**, clique no ✔ abaixo da pontuação. Também vote positivamente nas respostas que ajudaram você!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso *talvez* não seja possível, se for, não compensa o esforço, a utilização de um *array* deve ser mais prático.

```
var camadas = {};
for (var i = 0; i <= 20; ++i) {
    camadas["camada" + i] = 'Hello World ' + i;
}
```

Para recuperar um valor, basta especificar a chave `camadaN`, onde *N* é o número num intervalo entre *0* e *20*:

```
alert(camadas.camada5); // Hello World 5
//alert(camadas["camada5"]); // Sintaxe alternativa
```

Para mudar o valor de uma chave, faça:

```
camadas.camada5 = "foo";
camadas.camada6 = "bar";
// Sintaxe alternativa
//camadas["camada5"] = "foo"; 
//camadas["camada6"] = "bar";
```

[**`Exemplo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/d47oxmmd/)

### **Atualização**

Conforme este comentário:

> Estou criando uma web Page, para caucular as tensões no solo, cada
>   camada de solo tem **Altura** e **Peso** Especifico. Criei um *input* que a
>   pessoa digita a quantidade de camadas. Se o usuário digitar 5 por
>   exemplo, sera gerada 10 inputs, 5 para altura e 5 para Peso
>   Especifico... Entao para cada camada eu tenho que gerar as varáveis
>   para fazer os cálculos.... Por isso que preciso gerar as variáveis de
>   cada camada...eu criei elas como objetos, no caso uma nova camada eu
>   só instanciaria ela, mas ainda fico com o mesmo problema.

Utilize um *array* de *arrays*. Supondo que seja necessário que cada camada tenha altura e peso especifico, basta fazer o seguinte:

```
var camadas = {};
for (var i = 0; i <= 20; ++i) {
    camadas["camada" + i] = { 'altura': 'altura' + i,
                              'peso': 'peso' + i};
}
```

Para recuperar o peso e altura de uma camada, basta especificar a `camadaN` e as chaves, no caso, `altura` e `peso`. Veja um exemplo:

```
alert(camadas.camada1.altura); // Valor da altura da camada1
alert(camadas.camada20.peso);  // Valor do peso da camada20
```

[**`Exemplo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/j2sszwjs/)

Comment: Acho que ficaria melhor se as camadas fossem indexadas começando no 0.

Answer (score 4):

Algumas maneiras seguem abaixo.

1) Uma variável de escopo global:

```
window['nomeDaVariavel'] = 1;
console.log(window.nomeDaVariavel); // Irá exibir o valor '1' no Console.
```

2) Compilação via eval:

```
eval("var variavel = 1");
console.log(variavel); // Irá exibir o valor '1' no Console.
```

Porém minha sugestão seria utilizar arrays (`variavel[1]`, `variavel[2]`, etc.) ao invés de variáveis dinamicamente declaradas. Isso torna a manipulação da coleção muito mais fácil.

O snippet abaixo, em AngularJS, demonstra esta técnica: A propriedade `$scope.camadas` é inicializada como um *array* (via `$scope.camadas = []`). Observe após isso o uso de `push` (para adicionar um novo membro), `splice` (para retirar um membro) e `forEach` (que permite a iteração sobre todos os membros do *array*):

```js
$myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

camadasCtrl = function($scope) {
  
  $scope.camadas = [];
  //        ^ inicializando o array
  $scope.peso = 0;

  $scope.addCamada = function() {
    $scope.camadas.push( {peso: $scope.peso } );
    //               ^ Adiciona um membro ao array
    
    calcTotal();

    
    $scope.peso = parseInt(Math.random() * 1000000) / 100;
  }
  $scope.delCamada = function(index) {
    $scope.camadas.splice(index, 1);
    //               ^ Remove um membro do array
    
    calcTotal();
  }
  
  var calcTotal = function() {
    
    var total = 0;
    
    $scope.camadas.forEach(function(item) {
    //                ^ Para cada membro do arry, o código a seguir é executado
        total += item.peso;
    });
    
    $scope.pesoTotal = total;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    <div ng-app='myApp'>

      <div ng-controller='camadasCtrl'>
        Peso: <input type='text' ng-model='peso'> <button ng-click='addCamada()'> Adicionar Camada {{ camadas.length }} </button>

        <div ng-repeat='camada in camadas'>
          <button ng-click='delCamada($index)'> Remover</button> Camada {{$index}} : {{ camada.peso }} Kg           
        </div>
        
        Peso Total: {{ pesoTotal }}
        
        
      </div>
    </div>
```

O resultado é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Entendi sua intenção com o segundo exemplo, mas ali não tem nem variáveis nem escopo. São propriedades de objetos.

Comment: @bfavaretto Isso porque de acordo com o ECMA5, os objetos global primitivo e global VariableObject (o primeiro responsável por propriedades, e o segundo por variáveis) são o mesmo. De acordo com a mesma especificação, o que diferencia um do outro é o escopo; exemplos 1 e 2 usam o mesmo princípio. Note que ECMA5 declara o que é uma propriedade, mas não uma variável: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.26

Comment: Eu sei, isso é possível se as variáveis forem globais. Mas seu exemplo 2 fala em "escopo local". Os objetos que guardam o escopo local não são expostos à linguagem ([e mesmo expor o objeto que guarda o escopo global é opcional](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1)). O único jeito de criar variáveis dinamicamente em um escopo local é com `eval` – e como mostra sua resposta isso geralmente pode ser evitado  usando arrays ou objetos, o que também deixa o código mais claro e organizado.

Comment: @bfavaretto correto, obrigado - Vou remover exemplo.